# J2CA0138E:The message endpoint activation failed for ActivationSpec jndi/GG01(com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl)

Tags: java, websphere, ejb, ibm-mq, message-driven-bean

> jndi/GG01(com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl) and MDB application abc#abcd.jar#MdbListener due to following exception: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapterInternalException:MQJCA1011:Failed to allocate JMS connection,, error code:MQJCA1011 An internal error caused an attempt to allocate a connection to fail Linked exception is JcaExceptionBuilder.buildException

I am developing activation specifications at message driven bean using ejb+maven project and i deploying in websphere server in websphere application server not in liberty profile server. i am using ejb-jar.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi for binding.

While binding i getting this exception.can anyone please provide any example project matching above scenarios or any solution for above exception or any better way to achieve activation specifications

Websphere version-9.0.5

The exception cause I added below.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.connector.DetailedResourceAdapter InternalException: MQJCA1011: Failed to allocate a JMS connection., error code: MQJCA1011 An internal error cause at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:174) at com.ibm.mq.connector.services.JCAExceptionBuilder.buildException(JCAExceptionBuilder.java:135)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:394)
at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.acquireConnection(MessageEndpoint Deployment.java:295) at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointDeployment.<init>(MessageEndpoint Deployment.java:235) com.ibm.mq.connector.ResourceAdapterImpl.endpointActivation(ResourceAdapterImpl.java:558)
at at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activate Under RAClassLoaderContext(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java:661) at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint(ActivationSpecWrapperImpl.java: 374)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RAWrapperImpl.activateEndpoint (RAWrapperImpl.java:1122)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.RALifeCycleManagerImpl.activateEndpoint
(RALifeCycleManagerImpl.java:1825)
at com.ibm.ejs.container.MessageEndpointFactoryImpl.activateEndpoint (Messag EndpointFactoryImpl.java:152) at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startMDBs(EJBContainerImpl.java:4394)
53 more
Caused by: com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for queue manager 'MOWE with connection mode client and hostname 'xxxxxxx(1234) Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the queue manager to which you are connecting. For further information, review the queue manager error
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal. Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:531)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:215) at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:424)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQXAConnection.<init>(WMQXAConnection.java:67)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createV/ProviderConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:187) at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:7810)
at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQXAConnectionFactory.createProviderXAConnection(WMQXAConnectionFactory.java:98) at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createXAConnectionInternal(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:390)
at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory.createXAConnection(MQXAConnectionFactory.java:104) at com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ConnectionHandler.allocateConnection(ConnectionHandler.java:268)
.62 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ma.MOException: JMSCM00001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC FAILED") reason '2035' ('MQRC NOT AUTHORIZED')
```

Comment: Are there any more exceptions "chained" here (i.e. "caused by ..." etc.) that you might be able to share? Are you using the MQ resource adapter bundled with WAS: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/which-version-websphere-mq-resource-adapter-ra-shipped-websphere-application-server#7dotx_0_0_0 ?

Comment: Basically,i am new to websphere and ejb.In my project already running in listener port using Websphere mq provider.now ,i want to switch to activation specifications.i just used, already available host,port and Queue manager in listener.IBM Mq is protected by organisation.i can't able to see any IBM mq logs instead of i see internal tool to see msg count and messages.Can you please give any solution to this

Comment: The queue manager is rejecting your connection `reason '2035' ('MQRC NOT AUTHORIZED')`.  Check the queue manger logs or ask someone who can.

Comment: Some general guidance on reason code 2035 and how to access the queue manager logs on IBM Developer here > https://developer.ibm.com/learningpaths/ibm-mq-badge/mq-developer-cheat-sheet <

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the alias name in the WebSphere Application Server when creating activation specifications is one possible solution as that solved it for me.